# If the roots of $ax^2+2bx+c=0 (a\ne 0)$ are complex and $a+c<2b$ then

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

> Prove that $c<0$ and $4a+c<4b$

Since roots are complex 
$$4b^2-4ac<0$$
$$b^2< ac$$
Also $$2b>a+c$$
$$4b^2>a^2+c^2+2ac$$
$$b^2>\frac{(a^2+c^2)}{4}+\frac{ac}{2}$$
Then $$\frac{a^2+c^2}{4} < \frac{ac}{2}$$
$$(a-c)^2< 0$$
$$c> a$$

That’s all I could derive. How should I solve further

Comment: $(a-c)^2 < 0$ is not possible.

Comment: Why do you claim that $4b^2>a^2+c^2+2ac$?

Comment: @Gae.S. It's given in the question

Comment: @Fallen_Prince I don't see it.

Comment: @Gae.S. Look at the title

Comment: @Fallen_Prince, $a+c$ is not necessarily positive.

Comment: @Fallen_Prince I'm looking and I don't see it.

Comment: @GoranMalic Ofcourse . Otherwise $b^2 \not\lt ac$

Comment: You cannot square both sides of an inequlaity if you don't know that the numbers are positive,

Comment: @Fallen_Prince I don't see a problem with that happening when $a=-30$, $b=1$, $c=-1000$.

Comment: @Fallen_Prince Take $(a,b,c)=(-1,1,-2)$. Then $b^2<ac$, $a+c<2b$ but $4b^2=4$ is not greater than $(a+c)^2=9$.

Comment: Why is everyone pointing me out ?? Better Ask O.P for more clarifications and doubts.

Comment: @GoranMalic I get it, we need a reverse inequality too, but that really isn’t helpful. Plus, I never said what I did was right, that was specifically why I asked this in the first place.

Comment: @Fallen_Prince, because you, and not the OP, were doubling down and insisting that something was given, when it was not. Aditya, I don't agree that it isn't helpful. Counterexamples were given to show that you have to be careful when taking a square over an inequality. You weren't far off, since your derivation is valid assuming that $c>0$. But since you derived a contradiction, you must conclude that $c<0$ can't be the case, so $c\leq 0$. The analysis can then continue by examining what happens when $c=0$, and $c<0$ but $b$ less than, equal to, or greater than $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)= ax^2+2bx+c$ then $f(-1) = a-2b+c<0$, so $f$ is **negative** at $-1$

If $c>0$ then $f(0)= c>0$ so $f$ is **positive** at $0$ and since $f$ is continuous it must have real root. A contradiction so $c<0$

If $4a+c>4b$ then $f(-2) >0$ so $f$ is **positive** at $-2$ and $f$ has again real rooot. A contradiction again.

Comment: Could you elaborate further? I don’t understand what you mean by those contradictions.

Comment: A quadratic equation cannot have more than two `o` in its roots… ;o)